# Scifi story - travel to dark side of moon and involved some flesh eating insects

Tags: story-identification, books

If I remember correctly book contained three stories:

1. First story was related to travel to dark side of moon and involved some flesh eating insects
2. Second story was related to teleportation experiment went wrong. Experiment failed because a fly entered in teleportation machine.
3. I don't remember the third story but it was related to robots

Language of the book was Hindi but I have a strong feeling that it was translated from another language. Book was for kid/teenagers.

Need help to identify the book.

Comment: #2 sounds like the classic "The Fly" or a serious ripoff of it.

Comment: I think that #1 is H.G.Wells "The First Men in the Moon" (1901), #2 I agree has to be "The Fly" by  George Langelaan (1957). #3 may be an Asimov story but further information is required.